# stop fading effect when hovering sub menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

A div(sub menu) appears on hovering a element in menu bar in a fading effect, on hovering the div it stays there but 1st the fading effect take place I don't want the fading effect to take place. while hovering the div(sub menu), but the div(sub menu) should stay there.

```js
/*sub menu*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-courses").hover(function(){
        $(".sub-courses").fadeToggle(1000);
    });
    
});
```

```css
.sub-courses{
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 289;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-courses:hover {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a ui-sref="#" class="main-courses">COURSES <span class="caret"></span></a></li>

<!-- sub menu -->
        <div class="container-fluid sub-courses">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
                    one
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
                    two
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I also tried with mouseover and mouseout events but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain the fade effect, you can use the `stop()` method by adding the following to your javascript.

```
$('.sub-courses').mouseover(function(){
        $(".sub-courses").stop(true,true);
    })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-courses").hover(function(){
        $(".sub-courses").fadeToggle(1000);
    });
    
    $('.sub-courses').mouseover(function(){
     $(".sub-courses").stop(true,true);
    })
    
});
```

```css
.sub-courses{
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 289;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-courses:hover {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a ui-sref="#" class="main-courses">COURSES <span class="caret"></span></a></li>

<!-- sub menu -->
        <div class="container-fluid sub-courses">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
                    one
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
                    two
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This has some issue but I can get it from here, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just change the fadein time from 1000 to 0

```js
/*sub menu*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main-courses").hover(function() {
    $(".sub-courses").fadeToggle(0);
  });

});
```

```css
.sub-courses {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 289;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-courses:hover {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a ui-sref="#" class="main-courses">COURSES <span class="caret"></span></a></li>

<!-- sub menu -->
<div class="container-fluid sub-courses">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `.fadeToggle()` but just `.toggle()`. The parameter `1000` is the duration of the animation. Removing that gives the effect you want.

```js
/*sub menu*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-courses").hover(function(){
        $(".sub-courses").toggle();
    });
    
});
```

```css
.sub-courses{
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 289;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-courses:hover {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a ui-sref="#" class="main-courses">COURSES <span class="caret"></span></a></li>

<!-- sub menu -->
        <div class="container-fluid sub-courses">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
                    one
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">
                    two
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```